# Python: Comparing strings in a list with two different list lengths

Tags: python, string, list

I have two lists containing strings with different lengths.
Now I want to check if a string in one list is the substring of the other list
to create a newlist with the same length as the string_list.

```
string_list = ['expensive phone', 'big house', 'shiny key', 'wooden door']
substring_list = ['phone','door']
```

What I have done so far

```
newlist=[]
for i in string_list:
    for j in substring_list:
        if i in j:
            newlist.append(j)
print newlist
```

So it gives me

```
 newlist = ['phone', 'door']
```

But what I am trying to achieve is a list as following

```
newlist = ['phone', '-', '-', 'door']
```

Comment: This looks like homework so let me give you a hint. try using an else clause if i is not in j

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for` loops can take an `else` block. You can use this `else` block to append the `'-'` in the case where the string is not found:

```
newlist=[]
for i in string_list:
    for j in substring_list:
        if j in i:
            newlist.append(j)
            break
    else:
        newlist.append('-')
print(newlist)
# ['phone', '-', '-', 'door']
```

If you want the result to be same length as the first list, you need to put a break in the `if` so that if the two items are contained in one of the strings (e.g. `'expensive phone door'`), you won't make two appends which will skew the resulting list length.

The `break` also ensures the `else` block of the `for` is not executed when an item has been found.